# How to run regression with presence of constant and linear time trend in R?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

I have 2 time series X and Y.

I have already known how to run the regression with presence of constant, represented by the following equation:

[image]

The regression (equation with constant) shown right above I am simulating by running the code:

```
model_1 <- lm(y ~ x)
summary(model_1)
```

But, **I would like to run regression with presence of constant and linear time trend, represented by the following equation**:

[image]

What code should I use in order to run such regression in R?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `t <- seq_along(x); lm(y ~ x + t)`?

Comment: However, if you have time series it is very unlikely that you don't have some kind of auto- or cross-correlation. Sooner or later you'll need to deal with that.

Comment: Roland, thank you for the code. It seems clear to me. You are right, the cross- and auto- correlation are appropriate to be run on time series data and I did it. Now I am trying to run Engle-Granger methodology which includes Error Correction Model and that is why I need this regression with presence of constant and linear time trend.

Answer (score 4):

Roland, your baseline solves "time trend t addition" problem both programmatically and non-programmatically: The following is the `adfcs` function in my package `causfinder` (A package for Systemwise Analysis of Conditional and Partial Granger Causalities):

I have written **A**ugmented **D**ickey-**F**uller test code that takes into account **the usage of same (Common) sub-Sample for all of the lag orders** for the autoregressive process (**Tech info:** In all of the lag selection procedures in econometrics, same sub-sample must be used to determine the correct optimal minimum lag). See seq_along for ct case below:

```
adfcs <- function(t, max = floor(12*(length(t)/100)^(1/4)), type = c("c")) {
x <- ts(t)
x1d <- diff(x, differences=1)
x1l <- lag(x, -1)

x_names <- c("x1d", "x1l", sapply(1:max, function(i) paste("x1d", i, "l", sep="")))
for (i in as.integer(1:max)) { assign(x_names[i+2], lag(x1d, -i)) }
DLDlag <- do.call(ts.intersect, sapply(x_names, as.symbol))
DLDlag.df <- data.frame(DLDlag, obspts = c(time(DLDlag)))
DifferenceLags <- as.vector(names(DLDlag.df), mode="any")[3: (length(DLDlag.df)-1)]

lmresults <- array(list())
SBCvalues <- array(list())
AICvalues <- array(list())

for (i in as.integer(0:max)) {  

if (type==c("nc")) {    
if (i == 0) { lmresults[[max+1]] <- lm(as.formula(paste("x1d ~x1l")),data=DLDlag.df) 
SBCvalues[[max+1]] <- BIC(lmresults[[max+1]])
AICvalues[[max+1]] <- AIC(lmresults[[max+1]]) }
if (i > 0) { lmresults[[i]] <- lm(as.formula(paste("x1d ~ x1l+", paste(DifferenceLags[1:i], collapse="+"))),data=DLDlag.df) 
SBCvalues[[i]] <- BIC(lmresults[[i]])
AICvalues[[i]] <- AIC(lmresults[[i]]) }
}

if (type==c("c")) {     
if (i == 0) { lmresults[[max+1]] <- lm(as.formula(paste("x1d ~1+x1l")),data=DLDlag.df) 
SBCvalues[[max+1]] <- BIC(lmresults[[max+1]])
AICvalues[[max+1]] <- AIC(lmresults[[max+1]]) }
if (i > 0) { lmresults[[i]] <- lm(as.formula(paste("x1d ~ 1+x1l+", paste(DifferenceLags[1:i], collapse="+"))),data=DLDlag.df) 
SBCvalues[[i]] <- BIC(lmresults[[i]])
AICvalues[[i]] <- AIC(lmresults[[i]]) }
}

if (type==c("ct")) {    
if (i == 0) { lmresults[[max+1]] <- lm(as.formula(paste("x1d ~ 1+x1l+seq_along(x1d)",collapse="")),data=DLDlag.df) 
SBCvalues[[max+1]] <- BIC(lmresults[[max+1]])
AICvalues[[max+1]] <- AIC(lmresults[[max+1]]) }
if (i > 0) { lmresults[[i]] <- lm(as.formula(paste("x1d ~ 1+x1l+seq_along(x1d)+",paste(DifferenceLags[1:i], collapse="+"))),data=DLDlag.df) 
SBCvalues[[i]] <- BIC(lmresults[[i]])
AICvalues[[i]] <- AIC(lmresults[[i]]) }
}

}

list(which.min(SBCvalues), which.min(AICvalues))
as.data.frame(cbind(SBCvalues, AICvalues)) 
typespecified <- type
if (which.min(SBCvalues)==max+1) {
scs <- (max+2)-(0+1)
adfcs <- unitrootTest(x[scs:length(x)], lags = 0, type = typespecified)  
} else {
scs <- (max+2)-(which.min(SBCvalues)+1)
adfcs <- unitrootTest(x[scs:length(x)], lags =which.min(SBCvalues), type = typespecified)
 }
adfcs 
}
```

**Note:** Adding time trend non-programmatically:

> x <- rnorm(10)
>   x1l <- lag(x,-1)
>   lm(x ~ 1+ x1l + seq_along(x)) 
>       # Call:
>       # lm(formula = x ~ 1 + x1l + seq_along(x))
>       # Coefficients:
>       #  (Intercept)           x1l  seq_along(x)
>       # -2.107e-16     1.000e+00     2.645e-17

..... I checked the adfcs and it gives the same result with Eviews when proper calculation (in Eviews) is made:
**Note:** in Eviews (version <=7.2), the same (common) sub-sample is not used in ADF tests and hence ADF of Eviews is wrong! The properly and correctly realization of above code in Eviews is that:

**1.** Double click a variable; View; unit root test; ADF; "level,intercept"; Lag Length: Automatic Selection Schwarz: Maximum Lags=**14**". (14 changes according to dataset)

**2.** Arrange sub-sample by removing first samples: Assume data is 1960Q1 2009Q4 (200 obs). Then first **14+1** obs are removed from the sample: Sample - sample range pairs: 1963Q4 2009Q4. After providing the same sub-sample will be used, the ADF is performed.

**3.**  Double click the same variable once again; View; unit root test; ADF; "level,intercept"; Lag Length: Automatic Selection Schwarz: Maximum Lags=**14**". (Here a different number may appear other than 14 due to the effect of sub-sampling; delete that number in the box, and type 14). press OK.